# Circle $x^2+y^2=2$ is stretched by a scale factor $2$ parallel to the $x$-axis, find the equation of Ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

What is the quick method or formula to finding this answer? Also the method for finding the answer when the stretch is parallel to the $y$-axis, Regards Tom

Comment: $(x/2)^2 + y^2 = 2$ gives you the ellipse, stretched circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the circle have the old values of $x$ and the ellipse (stretched circle) the new values of $X$.  $X=2x$, or $x=X/2$.
$x^2+y^2=1$, so $(X/2)^2+y^2=2$, so the equation of the stretched circle is $(X^2/4)+y^2=2$.
Now forget about the circle, and $X$ versus $x$, the equation is $(x^2/4)+y^2=2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you stretch along an axis parallel to x- or y- axis, the semi-major/minor axis in that

principal direction is increased by that factor.

Stretched along $x$-axis : $\bigl(\frac{x}{2}\bigr)^2 + \bigl(\frac{y}{1}\bigr)^2 = 1$

Stretched along $y$-axis : $\bigl(\frac{x}{1}\bigr)^2 + \bigl(\frac{y}{2}\bigr)^2 = 1$

This happens to all curves with such two-fold polar symmetry... the characteristic dimension (like a,b) can be scaled up or down.